# How to Create Nextgen Custom gallery with album name

Tags: php, wordpress, nextgen-gallery

i am trying so long to making one normaly gallery useing by Nextgen gallery. but i can't make it yet. i found some way to show gallery thumbnail for speciy gallery and show album name but can't make that dynamicly and show together. bellow some code may be help

for show custom template file.

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Gallery
*/

get_header(); ?>


<?php
      $NextG = new NextGEN_Shortcodes;
      echo $NextG->show_gallery( array("id"=>2,"template"=>"myshow") );
?>





    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
<?php

if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() )
{
the_post();
the_content();
}
?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

for make custom nextgen gallery file

```
gallery-mytemplate.php

<ul id="slideshow">
  <!-- Thumbnails -->

  <?php foreach ( $images as $image ) : ?>
    <li>
      <a href="<?php echo $image->imageURL ?>" title="<?php echo $image->description ?>" <?php echo $image->thumbcode ?> >
                <?php if ( !$image->hidden ) { ?>
                <img title="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" alt="<?php echo $image->alttext ?>" src="<?php echo $image->thumbnailURL ?>" <?php echo $image->size ?> />
                <?php } ?>
            </a>
    </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

what i want ?

actuly i want my gallery page will have all gallery name top always and if i click any gallery name then show that gallery. see `http://www.evokephotoandvideo.com/2013-photo-gallery/` this url something like that. if can be possible also ajax load like ref. line then would be more nicer...

Comment: Nothing to do with [tag:next-generation-plugin] as defined in the tags.  Please read the description before slapping them on a post.  Also note that a single blank line of white space is always enough.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way for retrieving data from NextGen is to use NextGEN Gallery Database Class stored in ngg-db.php file. Open that file and there are all functions and explanations for taking the data directly from the database.

Example:

```
  $NextG = new nggdb();
  // get all galleries
  $NextG->find_all_galleries();
  // get single gallery
  $NextG->get_gallery( 2 );
```

Results are arrays, to examine them use `print_r` or `print_r2`:

```
function print_r2($val){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($val);
    echo  '</pre>';
}
```

That way you can take id or slug from all galleries and create custom url's like `http://www.evokephotoandvideo.com/gallery/slug`.

Additional info:

[WP Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite#Examples)

Comment: @danijel... thank you so much. i am going to try. lets see if can. i am not so pro in php yet. so will be hard for me i guess.. all i want to show all gallery name and thumbnail together like ref. link